# Laravel homestead is setup and works. But can't find files created

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I've just got my new Macbook Pro, and installed Homestead on it. Followed this link: https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead

I can view the site after installing Laravel on Homestead, but can't find where the files created are on my computer.

Here's homestead.yaml file
[image]

My browser
[image]

Code Folder
[image]

To check for any hidden files I've tried the same on Terminal
[image]

When I ssh into the Vagrant instance, I can see the file.

[image]

Where could the files be stored? Or am I looking at the wrong place? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it using the following steps.

I ran `vagrant provision` from the Homestead directory.

I was able to access the mac Code folder from ssh:

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.10.10
cd /home/Code
```

Just had to install Laravel again in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default it is in your User folder.  `Mac HD/Users/yourname/Code`

Answer (score 0):

Check your command by which you create the project. It looks like:
$composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist your_project_name
If no error occurs, a directory named your_project_name would be created under your Code path.
Good luck!